VS Code Custom Syntax Not Highlighting
I made a vs code syntax for calcscript but I cannot seem to get the hightlighting or the autocompetion working for my code.
This is my package.json:
{
  "name": "calcscript-syntax-extension",
  "displayName": "Calcscript Syntax",
  "description": "Syntax highlighting and autocomplete for Calcscript",
  "version": "1.0.2",
  "publisher": "TheSadDays",
  "engines": {
    "vscode": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "categories": [
    "Programming Languages"
  ],
  "contributes": {
    "languages": [
      {
        "id": "calcscript",
        "aliases": [
          "Calcscript"
        ],
        "extensions": [
          ".calcscript"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "grammars": [
      {
        "language": "calcscript",
        "scopeName": "source.calcscript",
        "path": "syntaxes/calcscript.tmLanguage.json"
      }
    ]
  },
  "icon": "icon.png",
  "scripts": {
    "vscode:prepublish": "node ./node_modules/vscode/bin/install",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/vscode": "^1.0.0",
    "vscode": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "calcscript",
    "syntax",
    "highlighting"
  ],
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/yourusername/calcscript-syntax-extension.git"
  }
}


this is my tmLanguage:
{
  "scopeName": "source.calcscript",
  "patterns": [
    {
      "name": "comment.line.calcscript",
      "begin": "'",
      "end": "$"
    },
    {
      "match": "\\b(AND|OR|NOT|<|>|<=|>=|<>|+|-|\\*|\\^|&)\\b",
      "name": "keyword.operator.calcscript"
    },
    {
      "begin": "\"",
      "end": "\"",
      "name": "string.double-quote.calcscript"
    },
    {
      "begin": "'",
      "end": "'",
      "name": "string.single-quote.calcscript"
    },
    {
      "match": "\\b(Abs|Acos|Acosh|Asin|Asinh|Atan|Atanh|Ceiling|Cos|Cosh|Degrees|Even|Exp|Fact|Float|Floor|Int|Ln|Log|Log10|Max|Min|Mod|Odd|Pi|Radians|Rand|Round|Rounddown|Roundup|Sin|Sinh|Sqrt|Tan|Tanh|Trunc|Value)\\b",
      "name": "support.function.math.calcscript"
    },
    {
      "match": "\\b(Now|Weekday|Day|Month|Year|Hour|Minute|Second|ScheduledTime|ScheduledTimeUTC|TruncToHour|TruncToMinute|Weeknum)\\b",
      "name": "support.function.timestamp.calcscript"
    },
    {
      "match": "\\b(Char|Clean|Code|Find|Left|Lower|Mid|Initcap|Replace|Rept|Right|Substitute|Trim)\\b",
      "name": "support.function.character.calcscript"
    },
    {
      "match": "\\b(TagAddNewHistory|TagAverage|TagAverageArray|TagHistory|TagHistoryArray|TagMaximum|TagMaximumArray|TagMinimum|TagMinimumArray|TagModifyHistory|TagStatistics|TagStatisticsArray|TagSum|TagSumArray|TagUpdateHistory)\\b",
      "name": "support.function.history.calcscript"
    },
    {
      "match": "\\b(if|then|endif|else|elseif)\\b",
      "name": "keyword.control.calcscript"
    },
    {
      "begin": "\\b(if)\\b",
      "beginCapturingGroup": 1,
      "end": "\\b(endif|else)\\b",
      "name": "keyword.control.calcscript",
      "patterns": [
        {
          "include": "#calcscript-block"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "begin": "\\b(else)\\b",
      "end": "\\b(endif)\\b",
      "name": "keyword.control.calcscript",
      "patterns": [
        {
          "include": "#calcscript-block"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "repository": {
        "calcscript-block": {
          "begin": "\\b(then)\\b",
          "end": "\\b(endif)\\b",
          "name": "meta.block.calcscript",
          "patterns": [
            {
              "include": "#calcscript-statements"
            }
          ]
        },
        "calcscript-statements": {
          "patterns": [
            {
              "include": "#calcscript-keywords"
            },
            {
              "include": "#calcscript-variables"
            }
          ]
        },
        "calcscript-keywords": {
          "match": "\\b(AND|OR|NOT|<|>|<=|>=|<>|+|-|\\*|\\^|&|SELECT|EXECUTE|FUNCTION|elseif|NOT)\\b",
          "name": "keyword.control.calcscript"
        },
        "calcscript-variables": {
          "match": "\\$[a-zA-Z]+",
          "name": "variable.other.calcscript"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}


This is my first attempt at this so any help would be appreciated!
Code in question if you were wondering:
'================================================================================

'                                 Variables

'================================================================================

    Fill_Rate_Height_Instantaneous_Trigger = 0
    High_Tank_Temperature = 0
    High_Tank_Temperature_Warning = 0
    Tank_Fill_Rate_Deviation = 0
    Tank_Fill_Rate_Warning_30m = 0
    Tank_Fill_Rate_Warning_40m = 0
    Tank_High_Level = 0
    Tank_Temp_Low = 0

    min = .0007



'================================================================================

'                              Above Hurricane Level
'                              ( Event Triggering )

'================================================================================

    if ( ( ( Level_1 + .1 ) > Hurricane_Heal ) OR ( ( Level_2 + .1 ) > Hurricane_Heal ) ) then

        HC_Level_Good = 1

    else

        HC_Level_Good = 0

    endif




'================================================================================

'                       Calculate Moving Level Limits
'                              ( Every 3 mins )

'================================================================================

'''''''''''''''''''' Add bad value condition ofr Level_1 ( What is a bad vaule? ) '''''''''''''''''''''

    if ( (  Level_1 > 1 ) AND ( Level_1 < 99 ) AND ( ( TagAverage( Level_1, ( Now() - ( min * 66 ) ), ( Now() - ( min * 60 ) ), 50, 0 ) ) > 1  ) AND ( ( TagAverage( Level_1, ( Now() - ( min * 66 ) ), ( Now() - ( min * 60 ) ), 50, 0 ) ) < 99  ) ) then
    
        Level_1_Moving_Limit = ( TagAverage( Level_1, ( Now() - ( min * 66 ) ), ( Now() - ( min * 60 ) ), 50, 0 ) )  + Max_Fill_Rate 

    else

        Level_1_Moving_Limit = 110

    endif


    if ( (  Level_2 > 1 ) AND ( Level_2 < 99 ) AND ( ( TagAverage( Level_2, ( Now() - ( min * 66 ) ), ( Now() - ( min * 60 ) ), 50, 0 ) ) > 1  ) AND ( ( TagAverage( Level_2, ( Now() - ( min * 66 ) ), ( Now() - ( min * 60 ) ), 50, 0 ) ) < 99  ) ) then
    
        Level_1_Moving_Limit = ( TagAverage( Level_2, ( Now() - ( min * 66 ) ), ( Now() - ( min * 60 ) ), 50, 0 ) )  + Max_Fill_Rate 

    else

        Level_1_Moving_Limit = 110

    endif




'================================================================================

'                               Event Triggers

'================================================================================

''''''''''''''''''''' Fill rate Hight Instantaneous Trigger ''''''''''''''''''''

    if ( ( TagHistory( Level_1, Now(), 0 ) - TagHistory( Level_1, ( Now() - ( min * 60 ) ), 0 ) ) >=  0) then

        Fill_Rate_Height_Instantaneous_Trigger = 1

    endif

''''''''''''''''''''' Hight Tank Temperature Trigger ''''''''''''''''''''

    if ( TagAverage( Temperature, Now(), ( Now() - 1 ), 0, 0 ) > Temperature_Max ) then

        High_Tank_Temperature= 1

    endif

''''''''''''''''''''' High Tank Temperature Warning Trigger ''''''''''''''''''''

    if ( Temperature > ( Temperature_Max - 5 ) ) then

        High_Tank_Temperature_Warning = 1

    endif

''''''''''''''''''''' Tank Fill Rate Deviation Trigger ''''''''''''''''''''

    if ( ( Level_Used_For_Compliance = Level_1 ) OR ( Level_Used_For_Compliance = Both_Levels ) ) then
        
        if ( Moving_Limit < TagAverage( Level_1, ( Now() - ( min * 6 ) ), Now(), 50, 0 ) ) then

            Tank_Fill_Rate_Deviation = 1

        else

            Tank_Fill_Rate_Deviation = 0

        endif

    else

        Tank_Fill_Rate_Deviation = 0

    endif


'     Tank_Fill_Rate_Warning_30m = 1
'     Tank_Fill_Rate_Warning_40m = 1
'     Tank_High_Level = 1
'     Tank_Temp_Low = 1



I tried researching but I could not find anything comprehensive about making vs code extensions, just to the point I am at now.

You have multiple errors in your .tmLanguage.json file

"repository" needs to be placed at the root level. (same level as "scopeName")
Not inside a "patterns" object.
also the + quantifier needs to be escaped \\+.
Oniguruma Regular Expressions
